# Adding noindex tags in Prestashop

Tags: pagination, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, noindex

I need to add noindex tags for filters and I am not sure which files should I edit in Prestashop (1.6). Is it pagination.tpl or some other file? Also, how should I format the command?

Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Product filters are handled by a module called `blocklayered`. If you want to change the way this module generates any output, you should edit the file `/themes/default-bootstrap/modules/blocklayered/blocklayered.tpl`. Change `default-bootstrap` by your theme name if you are not using the default one.

The `.tpl` is like a PHP file but is preprocessed by [smarty](https://www.smarty.net/). Any changes in the HTML should be fine, but you may need to read a little about *smarty* to change its code.

That said, if you want to prevent a whole page from being indexed, you should use the meta:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

At the *head* section of the HTML page. If you want to prevent a certain link to be indexed (I suppose this is the case), you can format the link this way:

```
<a href="//:stackoverflow.com" rel="nofollow" title="Stack Overflow">Stack Overflow</a>
```

The `rel="nofollow"` bit will do the trick.